# Does converting Oracle .rdf files to .rep do anything different than changing the extension?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oraclereports

I'm using Oracle forms and reports 11g. When I was told how to compile the reports (the .rdf files) I was told to just convert them to .rep files. I didn't think to check in report builder for a conversion tool, so I just went and renamed the extension of the file.

It turns out everyone else goes into Reports Builder, and exports the .rdf file to a .rep file. So I'm wondering if doing it that way is somehow different than just renaming the extension as I've been doing?

Comment: You seriously thought renaming a file would compile it?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I didn't think about it was the main problem. But when I asked why I couldn't generate the .rep files in reports builder, I was told I just needed to convert it. Manually changing the extension is how I've always converted files.

Comment: Not a very good way of converting files I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.
.rdf is the definition format of Oracle Reports.
.rep is the compiled format of Oracle Reports.

The runtime can execute both. Running .rep files is a bit faster, because precompilation is already done.

Comment: So by changing the file extension by hand, it's not doing anything except maybe my reports won't run as fast?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I'm doing and it's working fine. It's just confusing me why it works if I'm supposed to run it through reports builder.

Comment: Funny. Never tried it before. :-) But I think renaming it will be improvment.

Answer (score 0):

use Reports 11g menu Tools\File Conversion, provide the source file .rdf and target file .rep name and folder.

this will generate .rep file which is executable.